# Ssis Script can't find dll

Tags: c#, ssis

I am having issues with dll references in ssis scripting. I have an ibm dll that I reference on the C drive. Every time I reference it, it puts it in the folder C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\SSIS\c90f4b396fa54b3e9b7540b970489b79\obj\Debug\Interop.cwbx.dll

It runs just fine in visual studio (because it puts it in the temp dir), however when I import the package to management studio, it errors out at that script task, because it can't find it. This is all done on the server.

Any ideas/help is appreciated!
Brian

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know DLLs need to be registered in the GAC for SSIS to be able to use them.

Use gacutil.exe to register them and then try the pipeline again.

Comment: This of course presumes the GAC is strongly signed. Coming from IBM, it might be a reasonable assumption. Beyond that, you will need to import the DLL into the GAC on any server you plan to run the package from.

Comment: If the DLL isn't strongly named you are in for a rocky road!